# I have an asynchronous AWS.Request call that receives a result. How do I return a promise containing another result?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, promise, callback

I have a function foo() that executes an asynchronous request. This returns an AWS.Request that I can return and handle by the calling function. This will give me access to "data" received by the callback of the AWS.Request. What I want to do is be able for the caller to receive some other value, dependent on the value of "data":

```
function foo() {
    var user_request = awsrequest({'param1':val1, 'param2': val2}, 
                                   function(err, data) {
                                      if (data == condition) {
                                         return newVal;
                                      } else {
                                         return null;
                                      }
                                  });
    return user_request;
}
```

The caller works like so:

```
var request = foo();
request.then(function(result) {
    console.log("result is:");
    console.log(result);
}
```

"`result`" here is the value of "`data`" in the callback function in `foo()`, returned by the AWS request. I'd like to have the value of "`result`" be either `newVal` or `null` and available when the callback in `foo()` completes.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why are you passing a callback instead of calling the request's `.promise()` method?

Comment: The solution was to promisize it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was, as [Roamer-1888](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64294838/i-have-an-asynchronous-aws-request-call-that-receives-a-result-how-do-i-return?noredirect=1#comment113694161_64294838) said, to follow the answer in converting an existing callback API to promises, and I solved it like this:

```
function foo() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                        awsrequest({'param1':val1, 'param2': val2}, 
                                   function(err, data) {
                                      var result = null;
                                      if (data == condition) {
                                         result = newVal;
                                      } 
                                      resolve(result);
                                  })
                         });
}
```